# Making the vertical Menu as Sub Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code and I am using the associated CCS to create the vertical menu, which works well now I want to make it a sub vertical menu, so I can add the items if there any.

Code for HTML:

```
<div class="sidewidt">
    <h2 class="heading2"><span>Categories</span></h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-list categories">
        <li>
            <a href="category.html">Men Accessories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Hello</a></li>
                <li><a>World</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="category.html">Women Accessories</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="category.html">Computers </a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="category.html">Home and Furniture</a>
        </li>
        <li>
                <a href="category.html">Others</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the associated CSS for that, I think I had to amend css to make it work but right now I am literally confused.

```
ul.categories {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px
}
ul.categories li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E7E7E7
}
ul.categories li:last-child {
    border: none
}
ul.categories li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 11px 5px 11px 30px;
    background: url("../img/arrowcategory.png") no-repeat scroll 10px center transparent;
    color: #999999
}
ul.categories li a.active {
    color: #f25c27
}
ul.categories li a:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/arrowcategory.png") no-repeat scroll 10px center transparent;
    color: #333
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2toaqLw2/ what's the problem?

Comment: write your specific problem

Comment: @serg: Thanks, But can add a functionality to show on hover and hide on off hover

Comment: @user7346689 https://jsfiddle.net/2toaqLw2/1/

Comment: @serg, Thanks Dude, many Thanks, but i think we miscommunicated here, i want it to not to display underneath, it shows another layer so main menus should be stil and onhover shows the others menus in second layer